# onclick event is not keeping the change permanently

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a website in which I have to change the content of a div according to the option user select. When user click on the anchor onclick event handler changes the div correctly but just for an instant. I don't understand what is the problem with code. Here is the code:

```
<div id="main-content">
   <p id="para" style="display:block; width:200px; height:30px; text-align:center;margin:15px auto;">Choose an Option:</p>
   <a href="" id="add-student" style="display:block; width:200px; height:30px; text-align:center;background:rgba(19,7,163,0.30); margin:10px auto; padding-top:15px">Add Student</a>
   <a href="" onClick="addStudent();" id="delete-student" style="display:block; width:200px; height:30px; text-align:center;background:rgba(19,7,163,0.30); margin:10px auto; padding-top:15px">Delete Student</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function addStudent(){
      d1 = document.getElementById('main-content');
      d2 = document.getElementById('add-student');
      d3 = document.getElementById('delete-student');
      d4 = document.getElementById('para');
      d2.style.display = "none";
      d3.style.display = "none";
      d4.style.display = "none";    

      d1.innerHTML = "<p>Hello World</p>";
}
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check the console log and see if you are getting any errors

Comment: there is no error at all. It changes for just a blink of eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour for your anchor is to redirect you to a new page.

Return false from your function and click handler to prevent this.

```js
function addStudent() {
  d1 = document.getElementById('main-content');
  d2 = document.getElementById('add-student');
  d3 = document.getElementById('delete-student');
  d4 = document.getElementById('para');
  d2.style.display = "none";
  d3.style.display = "none";
  d4.style.display = "none";

  d1.innerHTML = "<p>Hello World</p>";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <p id="para" style="display:block; width:200px; height:30px; text-align:center;margin:15px auto;">Choose an Option:</p>
  <a href="" id="add-student" style="display:block; width:200px; height:30px; text-align:center;background:rgba(19,7,163,0.30); margin:10px auto; padding-top:15px">Add Student</a>

  <a href="" onClick="return addStudent();" id="delete-student" style="display:block; width:200px; height:30px; text-align:center;background:rgba(19,7,163,0.30); margin:10px auto; padding-top:15px">Delete Student</a>

</div>
```

Comment: @MuddassirIqbal Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

After your `addStudent()` code runs (on the `Delete Student` button), the click event "completes" by loading the address specified in the `<a href=""` attribute - in this case, it's blank, so the page is just reloaded. Return `false` from `onclick` to prevent this.

```js
function addStudent(){
d1 = document.getElementById('main-content');
d2 = document.getElementById('add-student');
d3 = document.getElementById('delete-student');
d4 = document.getElementById('para');
d2.style.display = "none";
d3.style.display = "none";
d4.style.display = "none";  

d1.innerHTML = "<p>Hello World</p>";

}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
<p id="para" style="display:block; width:200px; height:30px; text-align:center;margin:15px auto;">Choose an Option:</p>
<a href="" id="add-student" style="display:block; width:200px; height:30px; text-align:center;background:rgba(19,7,163,0.30); margin:10px auto; padding-top:15px">Add Student</a>
<a href="" onClick="addStudent(); return false;" id="delete-student" style="display:block; width:200px; height:30px; text-align:center;background:rgba(19,7,163,0.30); margin:10px auto; padding-top:15px">Delete Student</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is highly appreciable.